# ¿Por qué un array vacío es diferente de otro igualmente vacío?

Tags: javascript, json, array, comparaciones

Hace poco tuve unos pequeños problemas con una app que estoy haciendo, y resulta que me di cuenta de que una de las cosas por las que no funcionaba bien lo que estaba haciendo es que, en cierto momento dado al recorrer valores de un JSON, y comparar cada uno de los valores con otro JSON con las mismas propiedades pero diferentes valores, me di cuenta de que una de las comparaciones que hacia en el ciclo era un array vacio con otro array vacio (Si no existia ese contenido dentro de ese array o si solo habia sido inicializado como array), algo como esto:

```
let myJson = {

   title: "cualquier titulo",
   content: "cualquier contenido",
   links: []

}

let myJson2 = {

   title: "cualquier titulo 2",
   content: "cualquier contenido 2",
   links: []

}
```

Evidentemente en cierto momento al comparar los links del json1 con el json 2 traduciendolo a como lo veria o compararia el if me queda algo como:

```
if([] == []){

   //Instrucciones que no se ejecutaran

}
```

Sin embargo entonces me queda la duda de porque esto devuelve false??, es decir, ambos son arreglos, ambos tienen la misma longitud y ambos no tienen ningun valor dentro, ¿porque devuelve false entonces?

Comment: Puede que te interese esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703222/why-is-false-in-javascript) Creo que viene a decir que `==` compara si ambos son el **mismo** objeto (que es falso) y no si son **identicos** . Si te sirve el enlace avisame y traduzco la respuesta a español!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Javascript, al igual que Java o C#, considera que dos objetos no son iguales, porque lo que estás comparando realmente es el puntero al objeto. Por tanto `==` o `===` sólo sirven para comparar primitivas o para saber si el objeto es exactamente el mismo:

```js
function compara(a,b) {
  if (typeof a === 'object' && typeof b === 'object') {
    if (a === b) {
      console.log('Son el mismo objeto')
    } else {
      console.log('Son distintos objetos');
    }
  } else {
    if (a === b) {
      console.log('Tienen el mismo valor');
    } else {
      console.log('Son valores distintos');
    }
  }
}
const objeto = {};
const otroObjeto= {};

let copia = objeto;

compara(objeto, copia);
compara(objeto, otroObjeto);
compara(3, 3);
compara('a','a');
```

Un detalle importante a tener en cuenta: En Javascript existe el tipo primitivo `string` (que no existe en Java, por ejemplo), y además la clase String:

```js
let str = 'Hola';
let str2= 'Hola'
let objStr = new String('Hola');
let objStr2 = new String('Hola');

console.log('primitivos:', str == str2);
console.log('primitivos con ===:', str === str2);

console.log('objetos:', objStr == objStr2);
console.log('objetos con ===:', objStr === objStr2);
console.log('Mezcla:', str == objStr);
console.log('Mezcla con ===:', str === objStr);
```

Answer (score 4):

[Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38548356/is-an-empty-array-strictly-equal-to-anything-in-javascript) lo explica claramente.

Básicamente, lo que dice es que un array vacío sólo es estrictamente igual a si mismo. Es decir, la evaluación de una referencia a un array vacío sólo es estríctamente igual a la misma referencia que apunta al mismo array vacío.

En el caso que tu tienes, tienes dos arrays vacíos con dos referencias diferentes (una apuntando a cada uno), y dado que cada referencia es distinta entre si, la comparación entre ambas es `false`.

Para intentar aclararlme mejor, si miras la imagen de abajo, veras como variable1 (referencia a un objeto) es distinto a variable2 (referencia a un objeto con los mismos valores pero diferente en memoria).

[image: Variables que apuntan a regiones de memoria diferentes son distintas, aunque estas regiones contentan lo mismo]

Sin embargo, si las dos variables apuntasen a la misma región de memoria, entonces sí serían iguales

[image: Variables que apuntan a una misma región de memoria sí son iguales]

Un ejemplo sencillo para entender esto sería el siguiente:

```js
var a = [];
var b = [];
var c = a;

console.log("a y b son " + (a == b ? "iguales" : "distintos"));
console.log("a y c son " + (a == c ? "iguales" : "distintos"));
console.log("b y c son " + (b == c ? "iguales" : "distintos"));
```

Esto mismo pasa para cualquier objeto, no solo para los arrays, y aunque para ti te parezca lo mismo, para javascript no lo es.

Por desgracia no hay una forma de reimplementar el operador de comparación, con lo que tendrías que hacer una función específica para compararlos manualmente.