# Porque [] == [] me dice false si es true?

Tags: javascript, array

Porque cuando comparo 2 array vacios me dice false si deberia ser true?

[] == [] false

Comment: No estás comparando 2 valores primitivos, por el contrario estás comparando 2 objetos, y la comparación se hace sobre las referencias a memoria de cada uno. Al no ser variables que apuntan a la misma dirección de memoria, es lógico que devuelva `false`, ya que ambos objetos (que estás pasando de forma literal al comparar) tienen direcciones de memoria distinta.

Comment: Lectura muy recomendada: https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Comment: Mira esta pregunta, la misma duda que tienes la pregunte hace mucho https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/287433/por-qu%c3%a9-un-array-vac%c3%ado-es-diferente-de-otro-igualmente-vac%c3%ado

Answer (score 4):

Tal como digo en mi [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/520209/porque-me-dice-false-si-es-true#comment923381_520209), no estás comparando 2 valores [primitivos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Primitive), por el contrario, estás comparando 2 objetos. Un Array es un tipo de Objeto en Javascript, y todo valor no primitivo es un [objeto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Object), esto incluye Objects, Functions, Set, etc.

Tal como tienes tu comparación, aunque parece que estás comparando el mismo objeto, realmente no es así. Lo que sucede es que [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) siempre evaluará por valor cuando se trata de primitivos, pero evaluará por referencia cuando se trata de objetos.

Supongamos que asignamos 3 variables de la siguiente forma:

```js
const foo = [];
const bar = [];
const baz = foo;
```

Podemos pensar que tanto `foo` como `bar` son exactamente iguales, ya que son ambas `Array`s vacíos. Sin embargo, `foo` apunta a una dirección de memoria y `bar` apunta a otra dirección de memoria. Para el caso de `baz`, al estar asignada al valor de `foo`, entonces apunta a la misma dirección de memoria que `foo`.

Veamos:

```js
const foo = [];
const bar = [];
const baz = foo;

console.log(foo == bar); // false
console.log(bar == baz); // false
console.log(foo == baz); // true
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

En el caso específico de tu pregunta, al no estar los objetos asignados a una variable, Javascript simplemente asigna un espacio de memoria diferente a cada objeto que usas en tu comparación. Esto se llama *evaluación de literales* o directamente [*literal*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Literal). Y como ya hemos dicho que [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) evalúa los objetos por referencia, al ser estas referencias de memoria diferentes, el resultado de esta comparación es `false`.

Espero que esto aclare tu duda.